# How to authenticate with a private repo on DockerHub through the Docker.Dotnet client?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerhub

I am currently writing a microservice in .NET Standard that writes a Dockerfile, builds the Docker image associated with that Dockerfile (which implicitly causes a pull image), and pushes the image to a private Docker registry. Those Docker operations are all performed using the Docker.Dotnet library that MSFT maintains. I believe that this is mostly just a wrapper around calls to the Docker Remote API. The execution context of this microservice is in a K8s cluster hosted on AWS, or internally on bare-metal, depending on the deployment.

Previously our Docker registry has just been a private registry hosted on Artifactory internally, but we are migrating to a private DockerHub registry/repository/. With this migration have come some authentication problems.

We authenticate all of the pull and push operations with an AuthConfig that consists of the username and password for the account associated with the registry. The AuthConfig is either added to a Parameters object and then passed to the call:

```
imageBuildParameters.AuthConfigs = new Dictionary<string,
AuthConfig>() { { DockerEnvVariables.DockerRegistry, authConfig } };
```

…

```
using (var responseStream = _dockerClient.Images.BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync(tarball, imageBuildParameters).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
```

Or it’s (strangely, to me) both passed in a parameter and separately to the call:

```
ImagePushParameters imagePushParameters = new ImagePushParameters() { ImageID = image.Id, RegistryAuth = authConfig, Tag = "latest" };
_dockerClient.Images.PushImageAsync(RepoImage(image.Id), imagePushParameters, authConfig, this).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

We are currently getting auth errors for any of the various Docker registries I’ve tried for DockerHub, as such (where I’ve redacted the organzation/namespace and image:
{“message”:“pull access denied for registry-1.docker.io//, repository does not exist or may require ‘docker login’: denied: requested access to the resource is denied”},“error”:“pull access denied for registry-1.docker.io//, repository does not exist or may require ‘docker login’: denied: requested access to the resource is denied”

The list of DockerHub urls that I’ve tried is following, all with either the error above or a different “Invalid reference format” error:

- Hub.docker.io
- Hub.docker.io/v1/
- Docker.io
- Docker.io/v1/
- Index.docker.io
- Index.docker.io/v1/
- Registry.hub.docker.com
- registry-1.docker.io

Strangely enough, if I run it locally on my Windows system, the bolded URL’s actually work. However, they all fail when deployed to the cluster (different method of interacting with the Docker socket/npipe?).

Does anyone know the correct URL I need to set to properly authenticate and interact with DockerHub? Or if my current implementation and usage of the Docker.Dotnet library is incorrect in some way? Again, it works just fine with a private Docker registry on Artifactory, and also with DockerHub when run on my local Windows system. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide any more information that is necessary, be it code or configuration.